# The number of roots of a polynomial $p(x)=x^{12}+x^8+x^4+1$ in $\mathbb{F}_{11^2}$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, roots

I am trying to count the number of roots of a polynomial $p(x)=x^{12}+x^8+x^4+1$ in $\mathbb{F}_{11^2}$. Of course, I can plug every element in $\mathbb{F}_{11^2}$ into $x$ in $p(x)$. But is there any simpler way to do this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Which elements live in $\mathbb{F}_{11^2}$?

Comment: @AhmedHossam  I think $\mathbb{F}_{11^2}=\mathbb{Z}/(121)$ since the problem does not give any additional  information of the field

Comment: Is $\mathbb Z/(121)$ a field?  $11*11= 0$ and $11$ has no inverse.

Comment: @fleablood Oh thanks for pointing that out! That is my mistake!

Comment: $\mathbb F_{p^n} = \mathbb F_p[x]]/f(x)$ where $f(x)$ is an irreducible polynomial of degree $n$ in $F_p[x]$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint** Since $(x^4 - 1) p(x) = x^{16} - 1$ (which has no repeated roots), the roots $x \in \Bbb F_{11^2}$ of $p$ are precisely the elements $x \in \Bbb F_{11^2}^* \cong \Bbb Z_{120}$ that satisfy $x^{16} = 1$ but not $x^4 = 1$.

> Any element of $\Bbb Z_{120}$ has order dividing $120$ so any element of order dividing $16$ has order dividing $\operatorname{gcd}(16, 120) = 8$. Thus $p$ has four roots: If $\alpha$ is a generator of $\Bbb Z_{120}$, then $\beta := \alpha^{15}$ generates the subgroup of elements of order dividing $8$ and $\beta^2$ the subgroup of elements of order dividing $4$, so the roots are precisely $\beta, \beta^3, \beta^5, \beta^7$.

Comment: Oh!  Thanks! (+1)

Comment: Shouldn't we replace $\beta^3$ with $\beta^2$? because $\beta^2=\alpha^{30}$, $(\beta^2)^4=(\alpha^{30})^4=\alpha^{120}=0$?

Comment: No: Your computation shows that $\beta^2$ has order $4$, therefore $\beta^2$ is a root of the factor $x^4 - 1$ of $x^{16} - 1$ and not of $p(x)$.

Answer (score 2):

Notice: $$p(x)= (x^4+1)(x^8+1)$$

Clearly no number divisible by 11 is a root. So suppose $c$ is a root, so $11\nmid c$. By Euler we have $$c^{110} \equiv_{121} 1$$ and $c^4\equiv_{121} -1$ or $c^8\equiv_{121} -1$

In first case we get $c^2\equiv_{121} -1$ and so $c^4\equiv_{121} 1$ which is impossibile.

In second case we get $c^6\equiv_{121} -1$ and so $c^2\equiv_{121} 1$ and so $c^8\equiv_{121} 1$ which is impossibile again.

So it has no root in $F_{121}$.

Comment: Thank your for the answer!  But could you give me more clarification?

Comment: Prefect!!!!  Thank you so much! (+1)

Comment: This shows that the formal polynomial $p(x)$ has no roots in the ring $Z_{121}$, but the notation suggests OP is asking whether it has roots in the field $\Bbb F_{121}$.

Comment: @Travis So it has been shown more than needed?

Comment: No, the rings $\Bbb Z_{121}$ and $\Bbb F_{121}$ have different multiplicative structures---the former has zero divisors (namely the multiples of $11$) whereas the latter is a field and does not---so I claim that this answer does not address OP's question.

Comment: As you've pointed out, $p$ has factor $x^4 + 1$. In $\Bbb F_{11}$ this polynomial factors further as $(x^2 + 3 x - 1) (x^2 - 3 x - 1)$, and both of these factors are irreducible. Thus, we can realize $\Bbb F_{11^2}$ as, for example, $\Bbb F_{11}[x] / \langle x^2 + 3 x - 1 \rangle$, but since $x^2 + 3 x - 1$ is a factor of $p$, the image $\bar x$ of $x$ under the quotient map $\Bbb F_{11}[x] \to \Bbb F_{11}[x] / \langle x^2 + 3 x - 1 \rangle \cong \Bbb F_{11^2}$ is a root of $p$.

Comment: Even though this solution is not the one for my question, I still like this approach.